# Time loses when inserting datetime string with "-" between date and time mariadb

Tags: datetime, mariadb

Why MariaDb can't convert datetime string and insert it into datetime column if datetime is '2023-01-01 - 12:12:12'(will insert it without time and result will be 2023-01-01 00:00:00) for example? But in the same time mysql can ez insert it and result will be "2023-01-01 12:12:12".
So the main question is, why mariadb can't convert 2023-01-01 - 12:12:12 to 2023-01-01 12:12:12 and insert it and mysql can, and is it possible to change some specific config value at mysql server or something like that to avoid this strange behavior?

I tried to change my input format, tried to remove "-" from string for sql, but this is not option for me cuz i should swap a lot of places to use this "slash remover" the best option here is change some config at mysql server to prevent it and avoid "time loses"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a matter of timing.  MySQL has deprecated this, and will give a warning:

```
Delimiter '-' in position 11 in datetime value '2023-01-01 - 12:12:12' at row 1 is superfluous and is deprecated. Please remove.
```

In the future it will behave as MariaDB already does.

I suggest you do:

```
replace('2023-01-01 - 12:12:12',' - ',' ')
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/Zru5CidJ
https://dbfiddle.uk/Q8pIUOk1

Comment: so, it means that i can't do some 'ez way', i mean change some config or something like that? And globally(at sql server level) it is not possible to force mariadb to do it with warnings as in mysql? @ysth

Comment: i didn't see before that this query cause warnings, good hint from u, thanks btw

Comment: I don't think there is a way, unless you want to change your column to a character type; then you can fix the data in a before trigger.  I'd highly recommend just fixing your code.